# Using a variable in a expr regex command

Tags: regex, bash

I am using the following bit of bash ([sourced from here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) - I think)

```
bar=test_qux42_test
foo=(`expr ${bar} : '.*\(qux..\)'`)
```

The above returns qux42 successfully.

However, if I try the following it fails

```
baz=qux..
bar=test_qux42_test
foo=(`expr ${bar} : '.*\(${baz}\)'`)
```

I modify the command using a variable to customise the regex pattern and it fails. What am I doing wrong? How can I use a variable in the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are not expanded inside of single quotes, try changing them to double quotes:

```
foo=(`expr ${bar} : ".*\(${baz}\)"`)
```

Or you can move the variable outside of the quotes:

```
foo=(`expr ${bar} : '.*\('${baz}'\)'`)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `expr` for regex-matching in `bash`, which can perform it natively:

```
baz=qux..
bar=test_qux42_test
[[ $bar =~ .*\($baz\) ]]
foo=( "${BASH_REMATCH[1]" )
```